# Starting up GCompris on a RPI4 for a specific user

Tags: software-installation, raspberry-pi-os, debug

I have installed GCompris on a RPI4 which is running the latest Raspberry Pi OS.
I have 2 users. the default pi user and i also created a user call "student".
I can start GCompris when logged in as pi. When logged in as user, I click on the GCompris label and an hour glass runs for about 10 secs and nothing else happens. I'm able to start other games like MineCraft Pi but not GCompris. It's almost as if there's a lock for student to be unable to run GCompris.

Can anyone please help me fix this. This is for a student's ICT Lab and i don't want them logging in as pi to use GCompris.

thanks,

Nana

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else encounters the same issue:

```
student@LP3-WS1:~ $ gcompris-qt
...
* failed to open vchiq instance
student@LP3-WS1:~ $
```

Gcompris developers gave the solution by mail:

> you need to add your user to the video group (which is done by default for the default pi user, but not when creating new users).
>
> This command should fix it:
>
> `sudo usermod -a -G video userName`
>
> (replace userName by the actual name of the user, probably student in
> your case)
>
> Then log out and log in with the student user and it should work.